# How to find out the hosting provider of a website protected with CloudFlare?

Tags: web-hosting, cloudflare

We are doing a competitive analysis of our competition, but we can't figure out how to find out the website's hosting provider, if it's protected with CloudFlare. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do IP address lookups on any DNS records that aren't pointed to CloudFlare (most will be). This question however isn't about a website you [control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and is unlikely to help other webmasters.

Comment: This is a good question and should be moved to a relevant site, rather than closing this question.